# How to adjust the legend of a graphic generated in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could you help me adjust the legend of my graph?. I will insert an image showing how I would like it to look. I adjusted the `insert` of `legend`, however when I go to run the shiny, it doesn't show. I would like the legend to be under the graph.

Code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-02"),
       Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,6,1),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,4), DR02= c(4,2,6,0),DR03= c(9,5,4,0),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,5),DR05 = c(5,4,5,0),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,5),DR07 = c(2,5,4,0),
       DR08 = c(3,4,5,0),DR09 = c(2,3,4,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('date'),
                                 uiOutput('mycode')
                                 
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 tabsetPanel(
                                   tabPanel("", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                 
                               )
                             ))
  ))))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
 data<-reactive(df1)
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    entrydate<- dateInput(input = "Date2", 
                          label = h4("Choose"),
                          min = min(data()$date2),
                          max = max(data()$date2),
                          format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                          datesdisabled = disabled)
    entrydate$children[[2]]$attribs$placeholder <- "No selected date"
    entrydate
  })
  
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$Date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df5 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$Date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Category"),choices=c("No code selected" = "", sort(unique(df5$Category))))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    df1 <- data()
    req(input$Date2,input$code)
    plot(x=df1$DR02,y=df1$DR1)
    legend("bottomright",inset=c(-0,-0), legend= 3,title="The number is é:",title.col = "black", cex = 1.2)})
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your plot part to this

```r
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    df1 <- data()
    req(input$Date2,input$code)
    par(xpd=TRUE)
    plot(x=df1$DR02,y=df1$DR1)
    legend("bottomright",inset=c(-0,-0.15), legend= 3,title="The number is é:",title.col = "black", cex = 1)
  })
```

The key is `par(xpd=TRUE)`. You may also want to change the `inset` and `cex` values to get the best fit.
[image]